# Display all a div with the selected option | Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a selected option in my select tag. The purpose of the selected tag is to display all the stores in the div tag underneath. I've been searching around and some suggest `ng-selected`, `ng-init` and `ng-options`, but I have no idea which one or how I should do it.

I've managed to sort the stores based on their category which you can find in the select tag, but I can't display all of them :/

Here's my code:

```
<select style="width:100px;" ng-model="selectedCategory.category" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories">
    <option ng-selected="{{}}" selected value="">Visa Alla</option>
    <!-- {{ selectedCategory.category }} -->

</select>

<div class="row row-white" style="margin-bottom:10px" ng-click="browseShop(shop)" ng-repeat="shop in shops | filter:selectedCategory" ng-show="isAvailable(shop)">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <img ng-src="{{shop.img}}" />
        <br/>
        <span style="color:black">{{getCategory(shop)}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Really thankful for all the help I can get!

Comment: each `shop` in `shops` has `categroy` key?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? @ajaiJothi

Comment: So you want your first option to be a comma separated list of `shop in shops | filter:selectedCategory`?

Comment: @MartinNordström you are looping through `shops` with `ng-repeat`. So the `filter` you are passing actually search for value only in `category` key in each `shop` object i.e) `{category: YOUR SELECTED CATEGORY FROM SELECT BOX}` ->`selectedCategory`. Also make sure you `selectedCategory` model don't have any other keys. Currently I'm seeing only `category` key (`ng-model="selectedCategory.category"`)